# SQL Version Check Custom Condition

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a custom condition which will extract the SQL version and the service pack , but I'm not sure which expression to use and how to do so through ExecuteSql() and can the results only be displayed in the 'Numeric' string format ?

Comment: Are you talking about MS SQL Server here?

Comment: Yes I'm using MS SQL 2012

Comment: Have you tried Select @@version

Comment: Yes I have I'm aware of that , but I'm trying to do so through PBM.